# How can i sum value in room database android

Tags: android, mysql, kotlin, android-room

I want to know that how can i sum value in the room database .

Let say i have insert this value (10,000) in the room database and i want to insert new value to database (20,000) and i want the new value to be sum with old value not replace it .

how can i do that .?

example of code :

Database Table :

```
@entity 
class sum (

id : int , 
value : Long )

Dao :

@insert (onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
suspend fun insert (model :sum)

what shoud i use instead of above insert . 


@Query("SELECT * FROM sum")

fun getall () : LiveData<sum>
```

and in activity :

```
late init var : viewmodel : Viewmodeldatabase 
val textvalue : TextView

viewmodel = Viewmodelprovider(this).get(Viewmodeldatabase::class.java)

textvalue = findvidwbyid(R.id.text)
viewmodel.insert(sum(1 , 10000)

// when the above value insert , if there is an old value sum with it and not replace it or remove it 

viewmodel.getall.observe(this , Observer {

textvalue.text = it.value


)}
```

thank's guys for watch my code and help me .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add next method in your dao:

```
@Query("UPDATE sum SET value = value + :addValue WHERE id =:id")
suspend fun updateSum(id: Int, addValue: Long)
```

Then you can call it from your ViewModel/Activity

**UPDATE**

For single method for update/insert put these methods in dao:

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
suspend fun insertSum(model: Sum)

@Query("UPDATE sum SET value = value + :value WHERE id = :id")
suspend fun updateSum(id: Int, value: Long)

@Query("SELECT * FROM sum WHERE id = :id")
suspend fun getSumById(id: Int): Sum?

@Transaction
suspend fun updateOrInsertSum(sum: Sum) { // <-- this method updates value or insert new item, if id is not found
    getSumById(sum.id)?.let { updateSum(sum.id, sum.value) } ?: insertSum(sum)
}
```

Of course you should add method `updateOrInsertSum` to your repository and viewmodel as well
Then if you call for id = '1' for the first time value will be inserted:

```
viewmodel.updateOrInsertSum(Sum(1 ,10000)) // <-- id = 1, value = 10000
```

On the next call item will be updated with the same method:

```
viewmodel.updateOrInsertSum(Sum(1 ,20000)) // <-- id = 1, value = 10000+2000
```

Comment: i'm using your above code but nothing insert on database why ?

Comment: ```@Entity (tableName = "credit")
data class Credit(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id : Int?  ,
    var credittext: Long

)

Comment: ``` @Query("UPDATE credit SET credittext = credittext + :addValue WHERE id =:id")
        suspend fun updateSum(id: Int, addValue: Long)```

Comment: ```suspend fun update (id: Int, addValue: Long)= db.GetDao().updateSum(id , addValue)```

Comment: ``` fun getallcredit() = db.GetDao().creditall()```

Comment: ```fun updatecredit(id: Int?, addValue: Long) = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {


        if (id != null) {
            repository.update(id , addValue)
        }```

Comment: ``` viewmodel.updatecredit(1 , paymentRequest.amount)```

Comment: ``` viewmodel.creditall().observe(this, Observer {

            if (it != null) {

                Toast.makeText(this , "$it" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()```

Comment: The query should work, but method `update` will do something only if there is existing row with given id. So for insert new row you should call your `insert` method from dao, for update - described `update` method. If you call just `update`, then sure you'll see no effect

Comment: thank's body for your help . so i have to call a if statement like (if viewmodel.creditall == null ) { viewmodel.insert shoud be call and else viewmodel.update is called . is it true ?

Comment: Something like that. But in `if` condition you should check not `creditall`, instead - if there is credit with current id. I guess you need to add to dao one more method `suspend fun getCreditById(id:Int): Credit?`. Before insert you call it, if it returns null, then call insert, else - update.

Comment: updated my answer to use single method for insert/update

Answer (score 0):

In your Dao, I see that you use the function getAll(),
lets say that you save them into a list of integers

```
val list: List<Int>//list holding all of you data returned in the onChanged method of the observer callback(or the lambda callback in case of Kotlin)
```

lets say that you want to update the value at position 1:

```
@Update
public void update(newVal: Int);
```

and when calling the update function pass to it the summation of the old value coming from the "list" I mentioned earlier and the newValue

```
database.dao.update(list[1] + newValue)
```