# Stuck in data base room insert and update

Tags: android, mysql, kotlin, android-room

i hope , can to describe my issue clearly .

I want to Insert some value in the database room . actually i want when the new value is send to database sum with the old value not replace it .

for this resean i code some method to dao (insert , update , and getall data ) .

but the problem is i can't to code the correct if statement to say that when there is old value so the update method is called and new value sum with the old value and if there is no value in the database so the insert method calld . '

Code:

my table :

```
@Entity (tableName = "credit")
data class Credit(

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id : Int? ,
    var credittext: Long)
```

My Dao :

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM credit ")
    fun creditall(): LiveData<Credit>

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertcredit(model: Credit)

 @Query("UPDATE credit SET credittext = credittext + :value WHERE id = :id")
    suspend fun updateSum(id: Int?, value: Long)

 @Query("SELECT * FROM credit WHERE id = :id")
    suspend fun getCreditById(id: Int?): Credit
```

My repository :

```
 fun getallcredit() = db.GetDao().creditall()

 suspend fun insertcredit(model : Credit) = db.GetDao().insertcredit(model)

 suspend fun update (id : Int? , value : Long)= db.GetDao().updateSum(id , value)
```

My viewModel :

```
 fun creditall() = repository.getallcredit()

    fun insertcredit(model: Credit) = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {


        repository.insertcredit(model)


    }

  fun updatecredit(id : Int? , value : Long) = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {


        repository.update(id , value)

    }
```

activity :

```
  private fun paymentVerification() {


        val data: Uri? = intent.data

        val getpurchase = ZarinPal.getPurchase(this)


        getpurchase.verificationPayment(data) {

                isPaymentSuccess, refID, paymentRequest ->

            if (isPaymentSuccess) {

     // this is where i can't figure it out how do it .
            val id : Int ?= null

                if (viewmodel.getCreditById(id) != viewmodel.getCreditById(null)) {

                    viewmodel.updatecredit(1 , paymentRequest.amount)

                }else {
                    viewmodel.insertcredit(Credit(1 , paymentRequest.amount))
                }



                Toast.makeText(this, "افزایش موجودی شما انجام شد", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()




            } else {

                Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "در عملیات پرداخت خطایی رخ داده ، لطفا دوباره سعی کنید",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show()


            }
```

any help will be appreciated .

Comment: You asked the same question yesterday, please consider taking a look on my answer:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63892254/how-can-i-sum-value-in-room-database-android/63892604#63892604

Comment: i'dont know how use it body sorry

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63892254/how-can-i-sum-value-in-room-database-android/63892613?noredirect=1#comment113010438_63892613 . this answer it was helpful , if anyone want to khnow

Comment: I can help if something specific thing is not so clear